# How can i add variable in post() array in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I have registration form , in process i get all values by $this->input->post(); in the form of array how can i add Extra variables in post() array like date(),but instead of hidden form.THANKS

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like `$_POST['date']=date('Y-m-d');`in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter3 has not yes thought about such a method and it would be very helpful to have it soon.
Simply do this :

```
$posts = $this->input->post();
$posts['date_time'] = $date_time; // to add new variables
unset($posts['r_date']); // to remove variable
```